# emacs 29.2 /file/new frame shows Gtk error?

Tags: fonts, frames

Running a bare emacs, no init file.
Open emacs, Try new frame, I get
(emacs:20034): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 08:39:58.945: gtk_distribute_natural_allocation: assertion 'extra_space >= 0' failed
Resize the (tiny) frame and I get more (similar) errors.

(emacs:20277): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 08:43:31.822: gtk_distribute_natural_allocation: assertion 'extra_space >= 0' failed

(emacs:20277): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 08:43:36.724: gtk_distribute_natural_allocation: assertion 'extra_space >= 0' failed

(emacs:20277): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 08:43:36.741: gtk_distribute_natural_allocation: assertion 'extra_space >= 0' failed

Any suggestions please.

~/.Xresources reads

> cat .Xresources
> emacs.font: DroidSans-14

Comment: What distro? Are you building your own Emacs? If not, how did you install it?

Comment: Fedora 29, up to date. Emacs installed from their repo

Comment: I hope you mean Fedora 39. See https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2239456. If you have updated Emacs to latest available, you should add a comment to the above bug to point out that it's still a problem.

Comment: relevant bug report <https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2021-12/msg00049.html>

Comment: See also https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/e81e625ab895f1bd3c5263f5b66251db0fd38bd6/etc/PROBLEMS#L1444

Comment: Yes, sorry, typo, emacs 39. 
Tks for the replies.